# Find columns with different values in duplicate rows

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I have a data set that has some duplicate records. For those records, most of the column values are the same, but a few ones are different.

I need to identify the columns where the values are different, and then subset those columns.

This would be a sample of my dataset:

```
library(data.table)

dat <- "ID location date status observationID observationRep observationVal latitude longitude setSource
FJX8KL loc1 2018-11-17 open 445 1 17.6 -52.7 -48.2 XF47
FJX8KL loc2 2018-11-17 open 445 2 1.9  -52.7 -48.2 LT12"

dat <- setDT(read.table(textConnection(dat), header=T))
```

And this is the output I would expect:

```
   observationRep observationVal setSource
1:              1           17.6      XF47
2:              2            1.9      LT12
```

One detail is: my original dataset has 189 columns, so I need to check all of them.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Not certain of your intended result, but maybe `dat[, lapply(.SD, \(x) if(anyDuplicated(x) == 0) x else NULL ) ]` ?

Comment: Maybe `dat[, colSums(head(dat, -1) != tail(dat, -1)) > 0, with = FALSE ]`?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento your code produced the output I was looking for! If you wish to re-write your comment as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues, first, use `text=` argument rather than `textConnection`, second, use `as.data.table`, since `seDT` modifies object in place, but it yet isn't there.

```
dat1 <- data.table::as.data.table(read.table(text=dat, header=TRUE))
dat1[, c('observationRep', 'observationVal', 'setSource')]
#    observationRep observationVal setSource
# 1:              1           17.6      XF47
# 2:              2            1.9      LT12
```

Comment: I agree with this. While `setDT` and the assignment with `as.data.table` (with a _real_ named object) can be seen as synonymous, anecdotally (and without proof att) I have found that they are not, and in my use I now use the latter except when interactive and wanting code-golf quickness.